# Printing from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am running [a method](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#get_intents) which returns a dictionary which is formed like the following :

```
   {
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "goodbye",
      "created": "2017-08-18T18:09:36.155Z",
      "updated": "2017-08-18T18:09:41.755Z",
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "name": "hello",
      "created": "2017-08-18T18:05:48.153Z",
      "updated": "2017-08-18T18:06:06.004Z",
      "description": null
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "refresh_url": "/v1/workspaces/9978a49e-ea89-4493-b33d-82298d3db20d/intents?version=2017-08-21"
  }
}
```

This is all saved in a variable called response, which contains the dictionary for over 200 values.

If I print just "response", it prints all of the above, including "created/updated/description". I just want to print out the name value...and I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have read some posts here and tried the following -

```
for value in response:
  print(value['intent'])
```

but similarly, this prints out everything (including description/update date etc).

How can I make it *only* print out the name?

And for a bonus, how can I add the list of names into an array which I can then iterate over?

Comment: @Coldspeed thanks for your response. When I try print(value['intent'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers is the error I get.

Comment: what is `value['intent']`?

Comment: @coldspeed "for value in response:
  print(value['name'])" is what I am trying to run. response is the dict.

Comment: Well, it appears `response` is a dict when you gave us to believe it was a list of dicts. Can you please clarify the structure of your data? This is going nowhere.

Comment: @coldspeed "I am running a method which returns a dictionary which is formed like the following :"

Comment: Um, okay, then why do you show `{..}, {..}, ` which is exactly what a list of dicts looks like?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I wasn't aware. That is how Python printed them out :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have now updated the question with a full dictionary value. Apologies for the lack of clarity,  I wasnt aware this would cause an issue :)

Comment: Alright, written an answer, does that work for you?

Comment: @SimonKiely for your first line it's json not python dictionary. you need to parse it with json so that `null` values in json will be replaced by `None` when you load it as python dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to access the `name` attribute of each sub-dict in `intents`. This should work -

```
for d in response['intents']: 
    print(d['name'])
```

If you want this stored in a list, use a *list comprehension*:

```
names = [d['name'] for d in response['intents']]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was able to get much further in what I was trying to do thanks to this, and I understand what my issue was now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding names into  list and print it:

```
names = [intent["name"] for intent in response["intents"]]
print(*names, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my solution

```
names_list = []
for x in response["intents"]:
  print x["name"] # it will print all of your names
  names_list.append(x["name"]) # it will add the names into the names_list

print names_list
```

Hope it will help you :)